# Datepicker Issue

Tags: magento-1.7

I am going through a strange issue in my Magento module.

- I cant select dates in magento datepicker (calendar) if the present
  date is disabled.
- But, If I click any of the date in present month and go to the next
  month and comes back, then I can select the dates!!!!!!

My code below,

```
Calendar.setup({
        inputField : '_dob',
        ifFormat : '%d/%m/%y',
        button : '_dob_trig',
        align : 'Bl',
        singleClick : true,
        date: '25/6/2013',
```

Here by date attribute, I am trying to set a default date. But it too doesnt work. If I enables the present date to selectable, then the calendar works perfectly!

If anyone went through this before please share your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a solution...!

There is a `calendar.js` file in magento's default `js` folder. In that, there is a `currentDateEl` parameter. I changed it to `currentDateEl: 25/06/2013`... The issue is solved.